# iCal4j .ics Alarm/Notifications

Tags: outlook, notifications, icalendar, ical4j

I have the following snippet of an `.ics` file generated by iCal4j:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//Events Calendar//iCal4j 1.0//EN
VERSION:2.0
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTAMP:20110608T161848Z
DTSTART:20110604T213000
DTEND:20110604T222158
SUMMARY:Uplink Window
TZID:Europe/London
UID:20110608T162308Z-uidGen@10.37.129.2
DESCRIPTION:My Description
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTAMP:20110608T161848Z
DTSTART:20110604T230845
DTEND:20110605T001314
SUMMARY:Uplink Window
TZID:Europe/London
UID:20110608T162309Z-uidGen@10.37.129.2
DESCRIPTION:My Description
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

When I import this `.ics` file into Outlook or iCal each event has a notification 15 minutes before the start time (the little popup thing).  Is there a way I can disable these notifications?  We have hundreds of events per `.ics` file and don't need to be notified whenever one comes up, we just want to be able to view the blocks of time the events cover.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a setting of iCal and Outlook to add an automatic notification 15 minutes before any new event.  The `.ics` file was being treated as a new event.  Once I changed those settings in the preferences of the respective applications, I got the desired results.

User Error wins again.